# Yii2 - active record query search for a number in a string field

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2-advanced-app

i have a string field that contains a json string in my table. lets name that tbl_table

lets say it has these 3 records in it:

```
id    json
----------------
1     [123,45,1]
2     [23,4,5]
3     [7,8,9]
```

now I want to fetch records that contain a number in their json field (using active records in Yii2), so:

```
$res = Table::find()->where(['like','json','23'])->all();
```

this query returns these records:

```
id    json
----------------
1     [123,45,1]
2     [23,4,5]
```

this is not actually a wrong result but what I want is to return only the record with `id=2`. how can I do this?

and so for `['like','json','5']` or `['like','json','4']`  and so on? the numbers are similar but I want the exact number to be match.

and another question I want the last question answer with change in this part `['like','json',[4,5,6]]`.
in other words I want to pass an array to like operator and it automatically make an OR operation for each element. is it somehow possible? if not how can I iterate on array and make multiple Or_like conditions with last question functionality without multi query executions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use expression to use mysql functions and use JSON_CONTAINS function

```
use yii\db\Expression;
$expression = new Expression('JSON_CONTAINS(fied, value)');
$now = (new \yii\db\Query)->select($expression);
```

p.s json_contains begins from version MySQL 5.7

refs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html

Comment: is there any analog in mariadb?